# Apache PHP looping, will it block other accesses to the server?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, phalcon

I'm now using Phalcon as a framework to build my server, and I'm trying to implement a loop in a function.

For example, a user gives input from the page, the page uses ajax to post the input to a url of my server, then url on my server is doing some looping work which probably lasts 3 seconds.

Besides, the page will use another ajax to send GET to another url of my server, in order to get the progress of the looping. I stored the progress in session.

However, it seems that when the server is doing looping, it can't respond to other requests. From what I observed, I can see the 2nd ajax is sent multiple times, but the log I got only indicates function for the 2nd url is called only once.

Is this the limitation of Phalcon? PHP? Apache? or am I doing anything wrong with configuration?

Some demo code is shown here:

**Javascript**

```
function query(point)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/work", 
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {...},
        success: function(data, status)
        {
            alert(data);
            if(progressInterval)
            {
                clearInterval(progressInterval);
                alert("FINISHED");
            }
        },
        error: function(err)
        {
            if(progressInterval)
            {
                clearInterval(progressInterval);
                ertal("ERR");
            }
        }
    });
    progressInterval = setInterval(function()
    {
        alert("Send");
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/loadProgress",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }, 100);

};
```

**work.php**

```
function work()
{
    for($i=0;$i<3000;$i++)
    {
        do some work;
        store $i in session;
    }
    echo "finished";
}
```

**loadProgress.php**

```
function loadProgress()
{
    get $i from session;
    echo $i/3000;
}
```

Comment: question maybe to broad. depends too much on the exact setup you have got. if your PHP only runs in a single thread environment then it seems quite obvious to me that it can't respond to multiple requests simultaneously. but this might be a completely different story with php/apache running in multiple threads on multiple CPU-cores.

Comment: That makes sense. But I found what I missed was session_write_close()

Answer (score 1):

I found what I missed here.
After writing session, we must call session_write_close().
Or the whole server will be locked on session.